# How to get hardware info about remote linux servers?

Tags: linux, remote-server, summary

I've 120 remote linux servers with different OS's like `ubuntu`, `debian`, `alt` and I need to get hardware info (pci, usb devices, model cpu, hard drive etc). How I can do it easyest way by `bash` or something else? Tryed do via `ssh` and `inxi` but some servers closed for ssh connetcion and script exit.

````
cat server.list | while read i ; do ssh "$i" 'sudo apt-get install inxi' && ssh "$i" 'sudo inxi -Fxxx' > /tmp/summ/"$i".txt ; done```
````

Comment: have you succeeded doing same thing on a **local** linux machine? if do, then consider remoting.

Comment: It's work but just for the first host in list. List of hosts looks like column containing `username@host`

Comment: if local works fine. please give your current command that uses ssh to remote executing.

Comment: Try Ansible. It is some work to set up but then it works quite well.

Comment: Try Puppet as you'd have a centralized CMDB for all your endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I used `OCS Inventory` - it's better way for my task